# Regular expression number separated by a colon

Tags: javascript

I have input where ppl write :
PESEL:PESEL:PESEL...
Pesel is a number with 11 digits like 99040810123.

Now i have 123456789123:123456789123:123456789123:123456789123
How can i check with regular expression is it correct?
A fixed amount of PESEL is not provided.

I tried `/^\d{11}:/g` but it didn't work with last number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
/^\d{11}(:\d{11})*$/
```

The Regex allow 1 or multiple 11 character long numbers which are :-separated.

Comment: Why not just `/\d{11}/g`? Edit: ah it seems he's checking for validation and not just pulling out the digits.

Comment: this would match for all strings which has a 11 size long nunber in it, but I thought the hole string should be nummeric with a ":" after each 11 number block.

Comment: Yeah you're right, this works. All I would add is that the `/g` flag is unnecessary here since you're matching for a repeating capture group and asserting the beginning and end of the string.